# How can an ID card holder get a document certifying having legally entered Georgia?

Tags: immigration, resident-permit, students, paperwork

A Latvian guy I know entered Georgia yesterday on his ID Card, having been accepted for a study program at Tbilisi state University.

However, to get a residence permit, the public service hall states that he needs a document certifying that he entered Georgia legally.

Given that his ID card was merely scanned at Kutaisi airport, how can he get such a document? Should he go back to the airport and request it from the border police?

He does have his original boarding pass, which alone is not sufficient. Still, what can he do go get the necessary document?

Comment: Here are phone numbers listed for Kutaisi Airport Customs and Revenue Service office at the Arrivals hall (and open 24/7) +995 32 226 2233 and +995 32 226 2234

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out you can apply for an extract from the border crossing system at the Service Agency, which, in Tbilisi, is located at Petre Kavtaradze Street 5a. Takes a few days to issue.